# curl and URLSession returning different data

Tags: ios, swift, bash, curl, command-line

So I am trying to replicate a `curl` terminal call inside of swift.

Below Here is my command

```
 curl -v https://api.robinhood.com/orders/ -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token 111111MYTOKEN11111"
```

And it returns roughly

```
{"previous":null,"results":[{"key":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},{...},{...},...],"next":null}
```

And here is my swift code that I am trying to use to replicate it:

```
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.robinhood.com/orders/")!) as URLRequest
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("Token 111MYTOKEN111", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as String? {
                    print(str)
                }
            }
         })
```

Unfortunately this prints out `{"previous":null,"results":[],"next":null}`

What is causing this discrepancy between this command run in terminal vs my swift code? It is not an authorization issue because if you do edit the token it returns a completely different result.

Is there something that goes on behind the scenes in curl?

Comment: In your 2nd request.addValue you probably need to use the string `"Authorization: Token 111111MYTOKEN11111"` instead of `"Token 111MYTOKEN111"`.

Comment: Thats a good one. Unfortunately those are just stand-in strings for a much more secure token.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I wish I had more answers as to why this was happening but to my knowledge the header and the body of the requests were about the same between curl and URLSession, however, I cannot confirm since this is a secured request.

The solution ended up being to send the post request with Alamofire I guess in some instances that can actually make a difference beyond just how much easier it is to use.

I am still very curious why switching frameworks made a difference here.